# What does it mean when someone always wants more? Of anything

Tags: meaning

Always wanting more , of anything, never has enough,never contented with what they have

Comment: What did your dictionaries, thesauruses and search engines leave unclear?

Comment: Are you asking what the *words* "always", "wants", and "more" mean?  Or are you asking, what does it ***mean*** when someone always wants more?  That might be more on-topic at [Psychology & Neuroscience Stack Exchange](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm flagging this for closure as unclear what you're asking (as @Scott notes).

Answer (score 2):

Simply put it is GREED.
Dictionary defines " greed "  to be a selfish and excessive desire for more than what's desired or deserved, specially money, wealth, food, or other possessions. Example :

- His greed was his undoing.

Avarice,  covetousness,  rapacity or any synonym of.               ' Greed '  would mean the same. But GREED is how simple, yet how perfect!!

We call anyone as such GREEDY.

Answer (score 2):

**Insatiable** he was, always wanting more, never having enough and never content with what he had.

**insatiable**  [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/insatiable)

> impossible to satisfy

Some synonyms:

> - unsatiable
>
>   - quenchless
> - unquenchable